# Ionic 2 Image processing with Kofax

Tags: image, typescript, image-processing, ionic2, kofax

I am development an application where I need to use Kofax Image capture image extraction and text detection. Does Kofax has Mobile SDK for Ionic2?

Answer (score 0):

The Kofax Mobile SDK has a plugin for PhoneGap.  PhoneGap is based on Cordova, like Ionic, so you might be able to use this to work with Ionic as well.

You would want to read the Mobile SDK [documentation](https://services.kofax.com/support/products/mobile-sdk/3.x/documentation.php) to investigate if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mobile SDK do you need special licesing and reduce the scope of device can use your app. You can try to use RTT (real time transformation), define a Business Process synchronics and call from your app using the rest services, so you receive the result from transformation activity on line